# Connect elements in an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, panel, itemscontrol

I have a main window in which I put an ItemsControl, like this:

```
<ItemsControl
    Style="{StaticResource PanelStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" >
</ItemsControl>
```

The style is this one:

```
<Style x:Key="PanelStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <views:MyPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate >
                <ctrls:Element Colour="Green" Diameter="50" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So I end up having a Panel in the window, with a bunch of these Elements. Now, the question is:

I would like to connect these elements with lines, but I don't have any idea of how to do it. Suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: How does MyPanel know where to place the elements? There don't seem to be any view model property like X and Y or something like that. If the view model has these values available, I'd suggest to create another "line view model" with an item class that defines the endpoints of a line. Then create another ItemsControl with a Canvas as ItemsPanel and a Line control in its ItemTemplate. If all lines are connected, you may also use a Polyline that binds to a collection of Points.

Comment: There is no ViewModel. You set the position of the elements inside MyPanel accessing them via base.InternalChildren :)